# Install PlantUML without GUI

Tags: apt, docker

I want to install PlantUML in a Docker container. I tried this:

```
apt install plantuml
```

This depends on a full X11 and GTK installation, but I only want to use the command line tool, so I don't want to install unnecessary packages, as it considerably increases image size. Is there any way to install PlantUML without  GUI?

Comment: plantuml is a jar file so download that and put it somewhere on your system: for instance from https://sourceforge.net/projects/plantuml/files/plantuml.jar/download

Comment: Actually it doesn't depend on a full X11 and GTK install.

`plantuml` depends on `default-jre`  !

Comment: @RobertRiedl Then the Ubuntu dependency tree is seriously broken.

Answer (score 2):

By default, you must have X11 libraries installed. See: [Installation notes](http://plantuml.com/es/faq-install). Otherwise check how to use [Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

I think the best is to install [X virtual framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which can performs all graphical operations in virtual memory without showing any screen output.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install Xvfb
```

Then run by:

```
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
```

Then to specify which display to use, you need to export `DISPLAY`, e.g.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 # Select screen 0.
```

Then you can run `plantuml` to use that display.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Djava.awt.headless=true` if you have problems with x11:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /data/PlantUml/plantuml.jar ...
```

Source: https://plantuml.com/en/faq